# gauge-like calculation of DistributionSummary with micrometer and prometheus

Tags: spring-boot, grafana, prometheus, micrometer

I want to get a DistributionSummary over some domain data that does not change very frequently. So it is not about monitoring requests or sth like that.

Let's take *number of seats in an office* as example. The value for each office can change from time to time and there can be new offices and also offices get removed.

So now I need the current DistributionSummary over all offices, which needs to be calculated every time I think (similar to a Gauge).

I have a Spring Boot 2 app with micrometer and collect the metrics with prometheus and display them in grafana.

What I tried so far:

When I register a DistributionSummary, I can record all the values once during startup... this gives me the distribution, but calculated values like *max* get lost over time and I cannot update the DistributionSummary (recording new offices would work, but not changing existing ones)

```
// during startup
seatsInOffice = DistributionSummary.builder("office.seats")
    .publishPercentileHistogram()
    .sla(1, 5, 20, 50)
    .register(meterRegistry);

officeService.getAllOffices().forEach(p -> seatsInOffice.record(o.getNumberOfSeats()));
```

I also tried to use a `@Scheduled` task to remove and completely rebuild the DistributionSummary. This seems to work, but feels wrong somehow. Would that be a recommended approach? That would also probably need some synchronisation to not collect the metrics between removing and recalculating distribution.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5 * 60 * 1000)
public void recalculateMetrics() {
    if (seatsInOffice != null) {
       meterRegistry.remove(seatsInOffice);
    }
    seatsInOffice = DistributionSummary.builder("office.seats")
        .publishPercentileHistogram()
        .sla(1, 5, 20, 50)
        .register(meterRegistry);

    officeService.getAllOffices().forEach(p -> seatsInOffice.record(o.getNumberOfSeats()));
}
```

Another problem I just recognized with this approach: the `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint still returns the values for the old (removed) metrics, so everything is there mutiple times.

For sth like sla borders I could also use some gauges to provide the values (by calculating them myself), but that would not give me quantiles. Is it possible to create a new DistributionSummary without registering it and just provide the values it collected somehow?

```
meterRegistry.gauge("office.seats", Tags.of("le", "1"), officeService,
    x -> x.getAllOfficesWithLessThanXSeats(1).size());
meterRegistry.gauge("office.seats", Tags.of("le", "5"), officeService,
    x -> x.getAllOfficesWithLessThanXSeats(5).size());
meterRegistry.gauge("office.seats", Tags.of("le", "20"), officeService,
    x -> x.getAllOfficesWithLessThanXSeats(20).size());
meterRegistry.gauge("office.seats", Tags.of("le", "50"), officeService,
    x -> x.getAllOfficesWithLessThanXSeats(50).size());
```

I would like to have a DistributionSummary that takes a lambda or sth like that to get the values. But maybe these tools are not made for this usecase and I should use sth else. Can you recommend sth?

Comment: Your gauges approach looks pretty good. Is Prometheus not happy with it?

Comment: Hi @checketts, it works and is fine for sth. like table or bar chart, but for percentiles I would need many buckets (like DistributionSummary does provide with `.publishPercentileHistogram()`

Answer (score 0):

DistributionSummary has a config distributionStatisticExpiry could control rotate data. It's a workaround

But PrometheusDistributionSummary won't use this field

```
           case Prometheus:
                    histogram = new TimeWindowFixedBoundaryHistogram(clock, DistributionStatisticConfig.builder()
                            .expiry(Duration.ofDays(1825)) // effectively never roll over
                            .bufferLength(1)
                            .build()
                            .merge(distributionStatisticConfig), true);
```